# How can I re-order front matters (i.e., Title page, Abstract, etc.)?

Tags: document-classes, thesis, files

I am trying to put the front matter of my thesis as follows:Title page,
Abstract, Acknowledgements, Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures.

But I was not able to edit the class file to get that. The order that it generates is: Title page, Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures, Abstract, Acknowledgements

I appreciate any help.
I also have an issue with page number.
I want the page number at the bottom of each page but it is on top right, after page one of each chapter.

The class file is as follows:

```
    %% This is file `dalthesis.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% dalthesis.dtx  (with options: `class')
%% dalthesis.ins  (installation file)
%%
%% Dalhousie University Thesis Document Class
%% Version 2.2 &lt;2003/12/12&gt;
%% by Ian Nunn (2005)
%% Adapted from:
%%    Version 2.2 &lt;2003/12/12&gt;
%%    by Clyde Clements
%% Adapted from:
%%    LaTeX 2.09 `dalthesis.sty' file
%%    by Steven Matheson (1992)
%%    This was based on the Stanford University
%%    Ph.D. thesis style by Joseph Pallas (1988).
%%
%% This is a LaTeX2e class file which is intended
%% to meet the requirements for theses produced at
%% Dalhousie University, Canada.
%%
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%%
%% This is a generated file.
%%
%% This file is free and may be distributed as long
%% as the original source files, as listed above,
%% are part of the same distribution. (The sources
%% need not necessarily be in the same archive or
%% directory.)
%%
%% Any modified versions of this file must be renamed
%% with new filenames distinct from `dalthesis.cls'.
%%
%% Please direct questions, comments, suggestions, etc.
%% to: clyde@mathstat.dal.ca
%%
\def\fileversion{2.2}
\def\filedate{2003/12/12}
\def\docdate{2003/12/12}


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dalthesis}
   [\filedate\space v\fileversion\space
    Dalhousie University thesis class]
\newif\ifdal@title@page        \dal@title@pagetrue
\newif\ifdal@contents@page     \dal@contents@pagetrue
\newif\ifdal@tables@page       \dal@tables@pagetrue
\newif\ifdal@figures@page      \dal@figures@pagetrue
\newif\ifdal@dedication@page   \dal@dedication@pagetrue
\newif\ifdal@dedication        \dal@dedicationfalse
\newif\ifdal@phd               \dal@phdfalse
\newif\ifdal@draft@mode        \dal@draft@modefalse
\newif\ifdal@print@bib         \dal@print@bibtrue
\newif\ifdal@first@bibitem     \dal@first@bibitemtrue
\newif\ifdal@in@preface        \dal@in@prefacefalse
\newcommand{\dal@ptsize}{12pt}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand{\dal@ptsize}{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand{\dal@ptsize}{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{} % \dal@ptsize already set to 12pt
\DeclareOption{draft}{\AtEndOfClass{\draft}
   \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{report}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[\dal@ptsize]{report}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\setlength{\headsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2.5in}
\newlength{\dal@textheight@default}
\setlength{\dal@textheight@default}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\dal@textheight@default}{-2in}
\addtolength{\dal@textheight@default}{-\topmargin}
\addtolength{\dal@textheight@default}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\dal@textheight@default}{-\headsep}
\newlength{\dal@textheight@footer}
\setlength{\dal@textheight@footer}{\dal@textheight@default}
\addtolength{\dal@textheight@footer}{-\footskip}
\setlength{\textheight}{\dal@textheight@default}
\newcommand{\dal@set@textheight}[1]{%
   \global\textheight=#1%
   \global\@colht=#1%
   \global\@colroom=#1%
   \global\vsize=#1%
   \@floatplacement%
}
\newcommand{\dal@add@textheight}[1]{%
   \global\advance\textheight by #1%
   \global\advance\@colht by #1%
   \global\advance\@colroom by #1%
   \global\advance\vsize by #1%
   \@floatplacement%
}
\renewcommand\chapter{%
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
   \ifdal@in@preface\else\dal@add@textheight{-\footskip}\fi%
   \thispagestyle{plain}%
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\dal@chapter\dal@schapter%
}
\def\dal@chapter[#1]#2{%
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{chapter}%
      \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
         {\protect\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}#1}%
   \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
   \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}%
   \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   \if@twocolumn
      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
   \else
      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
      \@afterheading
   \fi%
   \ifdal@in@preface\else\afterpage{\dal@add@textheight{\footskip}}\fi%
}
\def\dal@schapter#1{%
   \@schapter{#1}%
   \ifdal@in@preface\else\afterpage{\dal@add@textheight{\footskip}}\fi%
}
\newdimen\dal@tempdima
\newdimen\dal@tempdimb
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth>\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \settowidth\dal@tempdima{\chaptername\ }%
    \settowidth\dal@tempdimb{\appendixname\ }%
    \ifdim\dal@tempdima>\dal@tempdimb
       \setlength\@tempdima{\dal@tempdima}%
    \else
       \setlength\@tempdima{\dal@tempdimb}%
    \fi%
    \addtolength\@tempdima{2.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi%
}
\flushbottom
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{40pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10pt}
\newcommand{\properpagestyle}{%
   \pagestyle{myheadings}\markboth{}{}\markright{}}
\brokenpenalty=10000
\linespread{1.37}\normalsize
\renewenvironment{figure}
               {\linespread{1}\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{figure*}
               {\linespread{1}\@dblfloat{figure}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\renewenvironment{table}
               {\linespread{1}\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\renewenvironment{table*}
               {\linespread{1}\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 0.8\baselineskip
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip \baselineskip
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip \baselineskip
  }}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
   {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
   {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
   {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
   {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \edef\test{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}%
  \def\@tempa{lof}%
  \def\@tempb{lot}%
  \ifx\test\@tempa%
     \addcontentsline{lof}{#1}%
       {\protect\numberline{\figurename\space\thefigure}%
        {\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \else\ifx\test\@tempb%
     \addcontentsline{lot}{#1}%
       {\protect\numberline{\tablename\space\thetable}%
        {\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \else%
     \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
       {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \fi\fi%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \normalsize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{%
   \settowidth\@tempdima{\figurename\ }%
   \addtolength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
   \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@tempdima}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{%
   \settowidth\@tempdima{\tablename\ }%
   \addtolength\@tempdima{2.3em}%
   \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{\@tempdima}}
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \linespread{1} % Set single-spacing
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark
    }%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}
    \color@endgroup}%
   }
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
    \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \linespread{1} % Set single-spacing
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth
    \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
         {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}%
   }
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\orig@thebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
   \clearpage   % necessary to get correct page number in toc
   \ifdal@print@bib
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
      \linespread{1}\normalsize
      \orig@thebibliography{#1}
   \else
      \newbox\dal@bib@box
      \newbox\dal@bibitem@box
      \let\b@group={
      \let\e@group=}
      \def\endthebibliography{\egroup\e@group}
      \let\orig@bibitem\bibitem
      \def\bibitem{%
         \ifdal@first@bibitem
            \dal@first@bibitemfalse
         \else
            \egroup
         \fi
         \setbox\dal@bibitem@box=\vbox\bgroup
         \orig@bibitem}
      \setbox\dal@bib@box=\vbox\b@group
      \if@filesw
         \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{toc}%
            {\string\contentsline \space{chapter}{\bibname}{\thepage}}}
      \fi
      \orig@thebibliography{#1}
   \fi
   }
}
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
\def\address#1{\gdef\@address{#1}}
\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\faculty#1{\gdef\@faculty{#1}%
   \def\@tempa{#1}
   \def\@tempb{Engineering}
   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
      \dal@fac@engineeringtrue
   \fi
}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\@submitdate{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
\def\degreeinitial#1{\gdef\@degreeinitial{#1}}
\def\bschon{\degree{Bachelor of Science, Honours}\degreeinitial{B.Sc.~(Hon)}}
\def\masc{\degree{Master of Applied Science}\degreeinitial{M.A.Sc.}}
\def\msc{\degree{Master of Science}\degreeinitial{M.Sc.}}
\def\phd{\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}\degreeinitial{Ph.D.}\dal@phdtrue}
\def\ma{\degree{Master of Arts}\degreeinitial{M.A.}}
\def\@title{}
\def\@author{}
\def\@university{University}
\def\@address{Somewhere}
\def\@dept{School of...}
\def\@faculty{Graduate Studies and research}
\def\@submitdate{%
   \ifcase\the\month\or
   January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
   December\fi
   \space \number\the\day, \number\the\year}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\def\defencedate#1{\gdef\@defencedate{#1}}
\def\@defencedate{%
   \ifcase\the\month\or
   January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
   December\fi,
   \space \number\the\year}
\newcommand{\MakeUppercaseWithNewline}[1]{%
   \begingroup
      \let\orig@newline\\%
      \DeclareRobustCommand{\\}{\orig@newline}%
      \MakeUppercase{#1}%
   \endgroup%
}
\newcommand{\dal@titlepage}{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \ifdal@draft@mode
     \begin{center}
         \large DRAFT COPY \\
         Printed \today\space\drafttime
      \end{center}
   \fi
   \null\vskip0.5in
   \begin{center}
      \hyphenpenalty=10000\large\MakeUppercaseWithNewline{\@title}
   \end{center}
   \vfill
   \begin{center}
      \rmfamily by\\
      \@author
   \end{center}
   \vfill
   \begin{center}
      \small A thesis submitted to \\
      the Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
      in partial fulfillment of \\
      the requirements for the degree of \\
      \vskip 2.5ex
      \MakeUppercaseWithNewline{\@degree} \\
      \vskip 2.5ex
      in \\
     Computer Science\\
      \vskip 2.5ex

      \vskip 2.5ex
      \MakeUppercaseWithNewline{\@university} \\
   \end{center}
   \vfill
   \begin{center}
   \small \@address \\
   \small \@defencedate \\
   \end{center}
   \vskip0.25in
   \begin{center}
      \rmfamily \copyright\ Copyright by \@author, \@copyrightyear
   \end{center}
   \clearpage
   }
\newcommand{\no@breaks}[1]{%
   {\def\\{ \ignorespaces}#1}%
   }
\newenvironment{dal@frontpage}%
   {\list{}{\listparindent \z@%
       \itemindent    \z@%
       \rightmargin   \z@%
       \leftmargin    \z@%
       \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
    \item\relax}
   {\endlist%
    \vfill
    \clearpage}
\newcommand{\dedicate}[1]{%
   \dal@dedicationtrue
   \gdef\dedication@text{%
      \begin{center}
         \large\em\null\vskip1in#1\vfill
      \end{center}
      }%
   }
\newenvironment{dedication}%
   {\newbox\dedicate@box
    \global\setbox\dedicate@box=\vbox\bgroup
    \begin{center}
    \large\em\null\vskip1in}
   {\vfill%
    \end{center}
    \egroup
    \global\dal@dedicationtrue\gdef\dedication@text{\copy\dedicate@box}}
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][d]%
   {\newpage
    \if s#1 % abstract to be typeset in single-space
       \linespread{1}\normalsize % Switch to single-spacing
    \fi
    \newcount\ab@page
    \ab@page=-\arabic{page}
    \prefacesection{\abstractname}}
   {\vfil
    \advance \ab@page by \arabic{page}
    \ifnum\ab@page>0
       \ClassWarningNoLine{dalthesis}%
          {Abstract longer than one page}
    \fi}
\newcommand{\ackname}{Acknowledgements}
\newenvironment{acknowledgements}%
   {\prefacesection{\ackname}}
   {\vfil}
\let\acknowledgments\acknowledgements
\let\endacknowledgments\endacknowledgements
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\def\frontmatter{%
   \typeout{Unavoidable over/underfulls may occur in the first^^J%
            few pages of dalthesis. These can usually be ignored.^^J%
            However, if uncorrectable errors occur, notify staff.}
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \dal@in@prefacetrue
   \ifdal@title@page
      \dal@set@textheight{\dal@textheight@default}
      \dal@titlepage
   \else
      \addtocounter{page}{1}
   \fi
   \dal@set@textheight{\dal@textheight@footer}
   \ifdal@dedication
      \ifdal@dedication@page
         \dedication@text
         \clearpage
      \else
         \addtocounter{page}{1}
      \fi
   \fi
   \ifdal@contents@page
      \tableofcontents
      \clearpage
   \else
      \addtocounter{page}{1}
   \fi
   \ifdal@tables@page
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
      \listoftables
      \clearpage
   \fi
   \ifdal@figures@page
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
      \listoffigures
      \clearpage
   \fi
   }
\def\mainmatter{\newpage
        \typeout{Dalthesis preface pages completed.}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \properpagestyle
        \dal@set@textheight{\dal@textheight@default}
        \dal@in@prefacefalse
   }
\def\beforepreface{\frontmatter}
\def\afterpreface{\mainmatter}
\def\nonumchapter#1{%
        \chapter*{#1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
   }
\def\prefacesection#1{%
        \chapter*{#1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
   }
\def\draft{%
   \newcount\drafthours
   \newcount\draftmins
   \drafthours\time
   \divide\drafthours 60
   \draftmins=-\drafthours
   \multiply\draftmins 60
   \advance\draftmins \time
   \xdef\drafttime{\two@digits{\the\drafthours}:%
      \two@digits{\the\draftmins}}
   %\let\ps@plain\ps@myheadings
   \def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
      \def\@oddhead{{\rmfamily\slshape Draft Version -- \today%
         \space\drafttime}\hfil}
      \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil}
      \let\@evenhead\@oddhead\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
   \renewcommand{\properpagestyle}{\pagestyle{myheadings}
      \markright{{\rmfamily Draft Version -- \today\space%
      \drafttime}}}
   \dal@draft@modetrue\properpagestyle
   }
\def\notitlepage{\dal@title@pagefalse}
\def\nodedicationpage{\dal@dedication@pagefalse}
\def\notableofcontents{\dal@contents@pagefalse}
\def\nolistoftables{\dal@tables@pagefalse}
\def\nolistoffigures{\dal@figures@pagefalse}
\def\nofront{%
   \dal@dedication@pagefalse
   \dal@contents@pagefalse
   \dal@tables@pagefalse
   \dal@figures@pagefalse
   }
\def\nobib{\dal@print@bibfalse}
%% switch the following two lines by commenting out one of them
%%\msc
\phd
\properpagestyle
\InputIfFileExists{dalthesis.cfg}
   {\typeout{Local config file dalthesis.cfg used.}}{}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `dalthesis.cls'.
```

Also this is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{dalthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@beginalgorithmic}{\small}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20.0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[]{appendix}




\begin{document}
\title{Thesis title}
\author{Mr. who}
\submitdate{2015} \copyrightyear{2015}
\defencedate{2015}



\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to ...
\end{dedication}
%\nolistoftables
\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
%\prefacesection{Abstract}
\begin{spacing}{1.25}
The abstract ...
\end{spacing}
\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------- Acknowledgments ---------------------------
% Go through all the papers and add their acknolwdgments here if it is applicable
\begin{acknowledgements}
\begin{spacing}{1.3}
The Ack...

\end{spacing}
\end{acknowledgements}

\mainmatter


%-------------------------------- Chapter 1-Introduction and Literature Review --------------------------%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter:introduction}
\section{Introduction and Motivation}
The amount of digital data 
\newpage
second page
\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt the class has anything to do with the order. Your *template* probably issues the respective commands in that order.

Comment: In my tex file I used \frontmatter command which is defined in this class file.

Comment: I don't have a template. How can I check if I have a template? there is no file in the folder except my tex and cls file. The rest are auto generated by the tex engine.

Comment: If you're at Dalhousie, then it's possible you need a newer class file to meet current requirements. [This one](https://projects.cs.dal.ca/dalthesis/) is from 2015. If you're not at Dalhousie, then why use their class file at all?

Comment: No, I am not at Dalhousie. My school provided this class file as a template for thesis.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but don't load packages unless you need them, don't load packages twice, and don't load both `color` and `xcolor`.

Comment: Respectfully, your school needs to make their own class file and not rely on 12 year old files from another university. I don't even see how you're overriding their built-in settings like their university name, city, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I used those packages for the rest of the thesis. I did not copy the whole thesis here for you to save space.

Comment: Mike, no worries, I edited the name, location, etc. The order was my only issue that was solved by the answer below. It is open source, so anybody can use it, right?

Comment: It's certainly legal, it's just a question of if it's sensible. If you and other students have to edit a provided class file to have the right university name, that's a sign of major problems with whoever provided the class to begin with. Especially if it doesn't match your university's or committee's other requirements of front matter ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is, add

```
\notableofcontents
\nolistoftables
\nolistoffigures
```

befor

```
\frontmatter
```

and

```
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
```

after

```
\end{acknowledgements}
```

**code complete**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{dalthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\ALG@beginalgorithmic}{\small}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[top=2in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{20.0pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[]{appendix}




\begin{document}
\title{Thesis title}
\author{Mr. who}
\submitdate{2015} \copyrightyear{2015}
\defencedate{2015}



\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to ...
\end{dedication}
\notableofcontents
\nolistoftables
\nolistoffigures

\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
%\prefacesection{Abstract}
\begin{spacing}{1.25}
The abstract ...
\end{spacing}
\end{abstract}

%----------------------------------------------- Acknowledgments ---------------------------
% Go through all the papers and add their acknolwdgments here if it is applicable
\begin{acknowledgements}
\begin{spacing}{1.3}
The Ack...

\end{spacing}
\end{acknowledgements}


\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter


%-------------------------------- Chapter 1-Introduction and Literature Review --------------------------%
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chapter:introduction}
\section{Introduction and Motivation}
The amount of digital data 
\newpage
second page
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice solution. Without editing the class file! Do you have any idea about the page number? Can I override the page-number setting in the body of the thesis. I want the page-number to be at the bottom.

Comment: @AMin I can't see the problem what do you mean?

Comment: For each chapter, the page number for the first page is at the bottom, but for the rest of the chapter it is on top-right. If you go to the second page of chapter 1, you will see the page number position. The question is: how can I bring the page number at the bottom, for all pages?

Comment: @AMin Ok, use `\pagestyle{plain}` after `\mainmatter`.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. I was thinking that \pagestyle might change the whole formatting setting of the page, but it just moved the page number. Thanks again.